# google cloud host and path rules

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using google cloud API (@google-cloud/compute).

I'm trying to fetch **Networking>Load balancing>Host and path rules**.

for now, I get only the configuration of backend service, I need to get the host and path rules.

I tried also use gcloud google command and didn't found some command that can give me this data.

Answer (score 3):

```
gcloud compute url-maps --help
gcloud compute url-maps list
gcloud compute url-maps describe <URL_MAP_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the hosts and path rules available to the specified project by using the following [Compute Engine API request](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/urlMaps/list):

```
> GET
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/urlMaps
```

If you need to use Google command line, then follow the answer provided by [Matthew Lenz](https://serverfault.com/users/306471/matthew-lenz).